# What is the single-word opposite of "misogamist"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, antonyms

A person who does not believe in the institution of marriage is called misogamist. But, what is a person who believes in the institution of marriage called?

Upon search, I found the opposites of misogamist as follows:

> 1. believer
> 2. optimist
>
> Link: http://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-opposite-of/misogamist.html

None of the above opposites appears to be specific − that is to say, pointing, in specific, to the believe in the institution of marriage. The opposites appears to rather indicate an optimistic attitude in general. To make the opposites specific, one will have to qualify the opposites − like, "believer in marriage". But, that does not fit the bill of single-word opposite of "misogamist".

What is the single-word opposite of "misogamist"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Philogamy** has been used in various books, therefore **philogamist** is the answer.

-neologism derived from:

[phil-/philo-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phil-)(Forming compound words indicating "fondness for", "favor of", "respect for".)

plus

[-gamy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-gamy#English) (Used to form nouns describing forms of marriage) (Wiktionary)

---

[Google Books:](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+philogamist&oq=define+philogamist&aqs=chrome..69i57.2581j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=philogamy&tbm=bks)

> " '**philogamy**' (the positive attitude toward marriage encouraged by the church)"
>
> "The State has no right to condemn these individuals to solitude and unhappiness, or to deny them civil recognition of spiritual generation, which is not less real than the corporeal, and is a result of **philogamy**."
>
> "I would define faithfulness to such mobile demes as **philogamy**."
>
> "We shall call this defence of marriage '**philogamy**', referring to Erasmus' Virgo misogamos (the girl who was opposed to marriage), the title of one of the dialogues in his Colloquia familiaria. "
>
> "Luther started noisily the trend to **philogamy**; he was personally quite direct in stating that he enjoyed sex with his wife. "
>
> "The misogamy which had typified the Church's approach to family life was now contested by a new **philogamy**."
>
> "Though overstated the argument has real merit, and is extremely useful for its discussion of the place of philogyny and **philogamy** in anti-monastic propaganda."
>
> "Prologue mocks **philogamy** with a sardonic flair more characteristic of a witty poet than of any pilgrim-narrator."
>
> " ' "Acrasial **Philogamy**?" Brother Edward, what is that?' 'That,' replied Edward, 'is an incurable malady to which young persons are subject.' "

Comment: I particularly enjoy the usage in the 5th quote.

Comment: "Gamophile" is even rarer than "philogamist," (from a Google Books search) but has been used to mean a proponent of marriage and similarly opposes "misogamist."

Comment: You missed:  "1845   S. Judd Margaret II. xi. 372   ‘“Acrasial Philogamy?” Brother Edward, what is that?’ ‘That,’ replied Edward, ‘is an incurable malady to which young persons are subject."  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/1762?rskey=O5ayaW&result=1#eid23298781).  Acrasial is "Ill-regulated, intemperate, uncontrolled", same reference.

Comment: @ab2 ~ appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

My ex-partner's sister was married to a man who had briefly been married, four times.

My ex, a bluff northerner with a unique British accent, from Sunderland, would roll his eyes and say of him:

'Laaaaaks weddin' kek!'

Meaning 'likes wedding cake!'

It always cracked me up, still does even now.

I thought it a great, oblique, and yes, sarcastic way to describe someone who is *in favour of the institution of marriage*.